# jqGrid multiselect not submiting the selected rows

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jqgrid, form-submit, multi-select

I am able to get jqGrid display my data. When I do multi-select and submit the form (jqGrid is obviously inside the form) then I am not able to get the selected rows in Spring mvc controller.
Here is my onClick event

```
$("#GetDataDetailsLink").click( function() {        
    var selectedRows;
    selectedRows = jQuery("#DataList").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
    var dataToSend = JSON.stringify(selectedRows);
    alert("dataToSend is =" + dataToSend);
    alert("selectedRows is =" + selectedRows);
    //non-ajax submit
    var url = "/underwriting-ui-web/taskDetail" + "?selectedTasks="+selectedRows;
    $("#DataGridForm").attr("action", url);
    $("#DataGridForm").attr("method", "get");       
    alert("action url is = " + $("#taskGridForm").attr("action"));
    $('#DataGridForm').submit(); 
    //ajax way of submiting
    /*
    $.ajax({
        url:'/dataDetail',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: dataToSend,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            alert('success: ' + result.result);
        }
    });     
    return true; 
    */
});
```

Some how jqGrid is overwriting my url and writing it's own url something like this

```
http://localhost:8080/myProject-ui-web/DataDetail?jqg_taskList_8=on&jqg_taskList_9=on
```

Instead of

```
http://localhost:8080/myProject-ui-web/DataDetail?selectedTasks=8,9
```

In ajax submit it is working. But I wanted it in non-ajax submit.
Any idea why this is not working in non-ajax submit?